# Incremental cloning with preview

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, backup, clone

I have a laptop with two internal disks (SSDs). I would like to use the second internal disk as a clone of my main one. I would like this to be a full system clone: If my main disk dies, I want to be able to switch to my second disk seamlessly. I want to achieve something similar to RAID 1, but without all the shortcomings of BIOS RAID / fake RAID. I've looked at software RAID, but Windows 11 doesn't support this anymore for the system drive.

Hence, I would like to find a backup/cloning application that I can run regularly to synchronize changes from my main disk to my second disk. I would like this application to:

1. populate the second disk with an actual copy of the files themselves, not with an image file that would then need to be restored
2. clone the Windows operating system to the second disk and make it bootable
3. in subsequent runs, only copy incremental changes, without needing to rewrite the entire disk
4. preferably show me a preview of the files that are going to be replaced or deleted on the second disk

FreeFileSync manages to achieve nearly all the above, except for the second point: It states that it is not intended to synchronize a live Windows system.

Does someone know another application (not necessarily free) that can achieve all the above? Alternatively, could I start off with an application such as EaseUS Backup or AOMEI Backupper for the initial clone, then use FreeFileSync for subsequent incremental updates?

Comment: You have answered your own question. Test booting from it after one sync, before you rely on it.

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @davidgo: Not to nitpick, but this is a question about computer software – specifically, about whether one exists that meets the above criteria. I'm not looking for a recommendation among various alternatives.

Comment: @RichardMajor I accept that - but its still a software recommendation request.  Changing "does anyone know another application" to "Can anyone anyone advise how" could put you on the other side of the line but changes the thrust of the question significantly.

Comment: As an aside - its very difficult to clone a running system disk without snapshotting/RAID.  Is your workload amenable to running in a VM?  That would allow abstraction of the "boot disk" and snapshooting the disk / pausing the running system to ensure consistency and also allows for a less hardware-specific environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I would try.

1. Using Ubuntu Live, `dd` disk 1 onto disk 2 so you start with a perfect image.
2. Setup FreeFileSync on disk 1 and have it copy changes to c:\ onto d:\ (you will need to setup the drive on disk 2 to a different letter to be able to clone).

   - You should identify which files to exclude cloning to avoid heavy i/o operations (such as pagefile.sys or hibernate.sys)
   - You will probably also need to disable system restore on c:\ to avoid high i/o
   - There may be other files similar to bullets 1 and 2 that will need to be disabled to effectively allow live cloning
3. After a week, pull drive 1 and put in drive 2 to see it will take over seamlessly.
4. If it is working well after testing it after one week, I would repeat the test once a month to make sure everything continues to work well.

I'm not sure this will work but it seems to be the safest test given your criteria.

---

### Alternative Options

- Periodically do a `dd` image using Ubuntu live of drive 1 to drive 2 overnight
- Create an OS drive on disk 1 with about 200GB - 300GB allocated to it. On the remaining space of disk 1, create a partition (D:) for user/setting files (e.g. move PROFILES to D:). On disk 2, create a partition identical to D:\ and clone D:\ to it. Create a `dd` image of the OS and store a copy on disk 2. The benefit to this setup is that your user files and setting are safe should a drive fail or Windows get infected with a virus (other than ransomware). Should Windows get corrupted, you can simply restore the image of the OS without needing to worry about user files or app settings.

Comment: Thanks Brian; that's a good suggestion. I'm going to leave the question open for a few more days in case someone can identify a single application that achieves both, but I'll pick your answer otherwise.